# How to make the API or the database create a new GUID during a POST event

Tags: asp.net-core, sql-server-2012, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I am using .NetCore 3.1 with Entity Framework for an API used by a javascript game.  I have a controller, that when used by the client,  has a POST event that creates a new Dungeon object in the database. I don't want the client to generate the 
ID on their end, I want the API or the database to do it.

Here is the POST controller method:

```
// POST: api/DungeonLists
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<DungeonList>> PostDungeonList(DungeonList DungeonList)
{
    _context.DungeonList.Add(DungeonList);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return CreatedAtAction("GetDungeonList", new { id = DungeonList.DungeonId }, DungeonList);
}
```

This, by itself just creates an empty GUID like this: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-00000000000.

So, I thought I might need to change my database.

For the column that I want to create the new GUID, I added  newsequentialid() for the default value, like this:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DungeonList] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_DungeonList_DungeonID]  DEFAULT (newsequentialid()) FOR [DungeonID]
```

But even with this change, I am still getting new items with a GUID of 00000000-0000-0000-0000-00000000000.

What could I be doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: The DungeonID has it's "identity" property set to true in the DB?  Is this an active api that you are already using and modifying?  Or is this new dev?  If it's new, you may just want to setup the GUID identity in code (EF Fluent API) and let it rebuild the DB  -- that might work better.

Comment: @BryanLewis it's a new NetCore 3 Entity Framework API that I'm currently developing.  But the database is much older.

Comment: And the identity property is "true"?

Comment: @BryanLewis thanks, so you think having the DB do it is better than have EF do it?  Thanks!

Comment: Well, you can do it either way.  In code, you would simply call DungeonList.DungeonID = Guid.NewGuid() before your Add() method.  But, not all Guids are equal.  newsequentialid() has some advantages because (as the name implies) it's sequential, which has performance benefits for the clustered index of a primary key.  Just using NewGuid() creates a random Guid, which is not as efficient for Sql Server.  The exact perf benefits are not an area of expertise for me, so I would suggest you research it.